# Object has no method error after no conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a site where I am using Scott Robbins pageslide to show/hide a responsive navigation.

For some reason the pageslide navigation works fine on the rest of the site but, when it gets to the contact page, it breaks: http://kevinpresbrey.com/contact

I took a look at the console in Chrome and I'm getting this error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method
```

I updated the jQuery call for pageside from this:

```
$(".open").pageslide({ direction: "right"});
```

To this:

```
jQuery(".open").pageslide({ direction: "right"});
```

and it's still blowing the error and causing the pageslide not to function on the contact page.

Like I mentioned before, it works fine on all the other pages, but the contact page. I have a feeling that the embedded form that was generated from constant contact might be causing the issue, but other than that, I have no idea.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try wrapping your code in document ready ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple versions of jQuery in your code, which could be causing the problem (even though some of the other code seem to be working). You have v1.8.3 and v1.8.2.

One of them is being pulled from:

```
http://www.formstack.com/forms/js/3/jquery.min.js
```

the other one from:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6
```

Fix that and your code should work.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, great. Well, that probably explains why it's breaking only on the contact page. Now I have to figure out a way to strip one of them out. I know that the contact form is a generated embed code, so I'm not sure how to get rid of that one. Might have to change up and make the template pull a different footer or something.

Comment: @ultraloveninja it's also using jQuery v1.10.2, you are going to have to clean up your code. Make sure wordpress is not pulling some jQuery on it's own somewhere.

Comment: Yep, I got it figured out...I think. It appears to be working now. I posted an answer below

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what it was.

Looks like it was partially from what Hanlet said. There were two version of jQuery that were being pulled.

Apparently when I commented out the code that pulls in jQuery within my functions.php file it defaulted to the version that comes baked in with Wordpress which is version 1.10.2 and that apparently fixed the issue.

So, yeah. Hooray...I guess?

Answer (score 0):

"pageslide" is not a build-in method for jquery selectors. You may want to double check if you include the "pageslide" javascript library / jquery plugin correctly.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Like do I need to place my call to the pageslide somewhere else? Or maybe place the pageslide library in the header?